# Division in the universal enveloping algebra

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, lie-algebras, noncommutative-algebra

Let $\mathfrak g$ be a (semisimple) Lie algebra, $\mathfrak b\subset \mathfrak g$ a Borel and $\mathfrak n = [\mathfrak b,\mathfrak b]$. Then I am interested in solving certain division problems in $U(\mathfrak n)$ on a computer. More specifically, we recall $U(\mathfrak n)$ admits a weight decomposition into components $U(\mathfrak n)[\xi]$. Then given a $P\in U(\mathfrak n)[\xi]$ and $Q\in U(\mathfrak n)[\xi']$ for some $\xi,\xi'$, I wish to find a $P'\in U(\mathfrak n)[\xi'-\xi]$ solving
$$
  PP'=Q
$$
The product here is the ordinary concatenation product. I know a (unique) solution exists from theoretical considerations. Furthermore all the coefficients are integers (in the PBW basis of $U(\mathfrak n)$, taking a Chevalley basis of $\mathfrak n$).

My current approach is sort of a brute force approach, and is unfortunately not very fast. I construct a (PBW) basis $\{f_i\}$ of $U(\mathfrak n)[\xi'-\xi]$, and a similar basis $\{g_j\}$ of $U(\mathfrak n)[\xi']$. Then for each $i$ we compute the product
$$
  A_i=Pf_i=\sum_jA_{ij} g_j
$$
Giving a matrix $A$. At the same time we define a vector $b$ by
$$
  Q=\sum_jb_j g_j
$$
Then we compute $P'$ by solving the linear problem
$A^\top v=b$, and setting $P'=\sum_iv_if_i$.

I know in the literature there is some theory of non-commutative Gröbner bases, in particular also for universal enveloping algebras. I feel like such theory might help to solve these kind of problems, but I don't immediately see how.